# Remove non-standard characters from a String in java

Tags: java, string, unicode

I have a string that contains a lot of text. There's some weird characters in it like the following: █ ✖ ✔ ♫ ♬ ▬ ★

This is just a small portion of what I have found so far. I tried using the replaceAll method but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a collection of all these types of characters somewhere, or even better yet, a library that is able to remove them?

Comment: You should specify the - sample input string, expected output string and your code.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "non-standard". These seem to be pretty standard Unicode characters to me.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work" is not a problem description. What did you try to do, and how *precisely* did it not work?

Comment: Define "weird". Do you think that they are text that someone intended to create and you just don't happen to want, or are they the consequence of text corruption?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over characters and check each whether it belongs to some category you define as "standard" (here such categories are: alphabetic, digit, whitespace, or modifier applied to previously accepted character):

```
static String standartize(String s) {
    if (s == null) return null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean based = false;    // is previous character accepted base for modifier?
    int c;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += Character.charCount(c)) {
        c = Character.codePointAt(s, i);            
        if (based && Character.getType(c) == Character.MODIFIER_SYMBOL) {  
            sb.appendCodePoint(c);               
        } else if (Character.isAlphabetic(c) || Character.isDigit(c)) {
            sb.appendCodePoint(c);
            based = true;
        } else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            sb.appendCodePoint(c);
            based = false;
        } else {
            based = false;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

You can add/remove checks in `else if` to widen/narrow range of characters you consider "standard": [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) has many static `isXxxx()` methods to test if a character belongs to some category.

Please notice that iterated are not `char` items, but `int` codepoints. This is made to process not only UTF-16 chars, but surrogate pairs as well.

Comment: This won't work with Unicode codepoints that are encoded in two UTF-16 code units (`char`). Nor will it retain "combining character" codepoints that might not be considered "weird" when combined with a preceding base character..

Comment: @TomBlodget well, you're right. I updated the answer to handle surrogate pairs and modifier characters as well. Thank you for valuable notice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only ASCII Characters in your string, you can loop through the length of the string and check wether ASCII value is between 65 - 90(A-Z) or 97 - 122(a-z) or 48-57(0 - 9)

Comment: If you are not sure about the question, you should not try to answer it. You should leave a comment (as you can see) asking for clarification.